# Does Typescript provide a "convenience interface" for simple dictionaries?

Tags: typescript

I'm not asking how to implement a dictionary in Typescript, rather, I'm asking: "Does Typescript come with convenience interfaces for common dictionary use cases?"

Example:

I am writing an application and need a dictionary of type `T`.

```
interface GenericDict<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

let dictionary: GenericDict<string[]> = {};
dictionary["example"] = ["foo"];
// Works fine!
```

This code is valid, but is essentially boiler plate. Is there any interface that comes in Typescript (`lib.d.ts`) that does this for me automatically? It could save some lines of code and keep my codebase cleaner, and I really don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Considering it's basic functionality of an object in JavaScript, probably not. Just declare it as `any`, and you can do the same thing. It's not like there are methods like `Add` or whatever like a C# `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` type. Or, better yet, if you can target ES2015, use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: Hi Rick, there are some uncertainties about what you really asked for here, see the comments in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, typescript does not come with any kind of build-in classes/interfaces/utilities like this. Typescript is basically just a language and a compiler, and the `index signature` that you have used in your example above is the only syntax TS provides in regards to the typing of associative collections.

Point 6 in their [design non-goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals):

> Provide additional runtime functionality or libraries. Instead, use
>   TypeScript to describe existing libraries.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a valid answer.  Per the question `I'm not asking how to implement a dictionary in Typescript, rather, I'm asking: "Does Typescript come with convinience interfaces for common dictionary use cases?"` The answer is not about functionality but convenience interfaces, which Typescript does supply.

Comment: @ArcSine You mean the `index signature` syntax that the questioner already knows about and has used in his example?

Comment: He uses it in an interface, but it can be used directly, which I think is what he was getting at.  Basically can he have typed dictionaries without defining a new interface.

Comment: @ArcSine Hmm... We obviously interpreted the question differently, but I see what you mean. Let's see if we get any clarifications.

Comment: This answer is still correct. I was specifically asking if Typescript already comes with the interface that I wrote by hand in the example. Writing the interface inline as some had suggested does satisfy my question, because I am still "repeating myself". My goal was to avoid writing an interface and to just use one that comes with Typescript. The question simply asks whether or not this simple interface came with the compiler or `lib.d.ts`.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript supports the standard notation

`let dict:{[key:string]:string[]} = {};`

To type the `key` and the `value`.  The only valid values for key are `number` and `string`

Comment: This might be useful for some users in this situation (I upvoted it), but it does not specifically answer my question. I was trying to avoid writing boilerplate interface code. I wanted to know if the interface I wrote came with `lib.d.ts` or the compiler.

Comment: `let dict:{[key:string}:string[]}` is how you bound the value of an object in Typescript.  ES6 has a built-in dictionary type that you can use with typescript https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#l17-25, but this is an actual dictionary type vs just typing an object.

Comment: Still not quite what I was looking for, but useful nonetheless. Thanks for the heads up on that one.